# image and carousel not responsive bootstrap5.2

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a problem of responsiveness. When I open my website on the phone, the icon images that I put in the `<i class="img-fluid material-icons">` tag disappear while they are visible on the computer. I tried to add img-fluid from bootstrap but it doesn't work on it I don't understand why. On this link you can see all the code in full https://jsfiddle.net/z3hx2Lcr and in this link you can see result https://testportfolio111.000webhostapp.com/ I also have a responsivity problem in the carousel since I put the text effects in it. When I open the site on my phone the carousel goes down, I tried to fix this problem but I can't. Can anyone give me the solution?

Answer (score 0):

there is a problem on your bottom sections, the element with class .skills-bar
break the page and caused gap from right because it has fixed width value
so change it to this code

```
.skills-bar {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 600px;
}
```

and in the container which your icons are change this in mobile version
instead of

```
<div class="col animationtextinleft"></div>
<div class="col"></div>
<div class="col animationtextinright"></div>
```

use this

```
<div class="col-12 animationtextinleft"></div>
<div class="col-12"></div>
<div class="col-12 animationtextinright"></div>
```

about your slider:
your .carousel-item has height: 100vh
change it to height: auto in mobile version
and the reason why it's text is not showing is these slides(carousel-caption) get the class d-none

Comment: ok thanks for your help i have change 100vh to auto carousel stoped to down but this is not responsive and don't see the animation text... and where i have icon it's col-2 <div class="col-2"> <i class="img-fluid material-icons"><img class="img-fluid w-100" src="images/5902216.png" alt="" style="width: 100%;"></i> </div> like this

Comment: i need carousel like in this website https://www.mathieu-crevoulin.com/

Comment: your slider text got the class d-none which make theme disappear (display:none) you have to remove that class from theme (may be there is a property on plugin or library you use to enable this) , and about the icons , you can find theme by inspect the page it is in the section after your slider section

Comment: ok thanks but how do responsive carousel? animation text if you see in code this is in  css only

Comment: for example 
```
<div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block d-flex h-50 align-items-center justify-content-center"></div>
```
in your slider is like this just remove the d-none from it to have text in mobile version too

Comment: thanks i have remove now seeing animation text in mobile but carousel not responsive in mobile i mean carousel not in full screen of mobile, how can i do for it's be in a full screen mobile?

Comment: I think the the slider in the website that you sent, is calculating the height of the section in mobile version and give the right height to it, I didnt see something like this in your slider but in case you want your slider looks bigger just revert the carousel-item height to 100vh and give the image inside these styles
height: 100%; object-fit: cover
test this and see if this can help you

Comment: ok, i have try to do this it's not changed i have back like you talk before (.carousel-item {
  height: auto;
})

Comment: I have find something, when i do .carousel-item { height: 100vh; min-height: 350px; background: no-repeat center center scroll; -webkit-background-size: cover; -moz-background-size: cover; -o-background-size: cover; background-size: cover;    it's full screen but error this is in animation text and slider down in full screen mobile